# Update an empty column with a geometry selection (ST_Centroid) from the same table (or another one)

Tags: postgis

I'm admitting that PostGIS is really giving me headache and it's not my strong point.

I have a table `my_table` with columns: `id_point` , `point` (point n°, contains numbers from 1 to 5), `geometry` (geometry of each point), `road` (road number), `geom_moyenne`.

Geometry has a point geometry for each point, geom_moyenne is empty.

I have made a selection to get an average geometry for each road (each road has 5 points with different geometries and I want to have a kind of a middle position point for each road):

```sql
SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Union(geometry)) AS geom_moyenne , road
FROM my_table
GROUP BY road;
```

Now I want to put the results of my selection in my empty geom_moyenne column and I failed miserably. Neither of these two is working. What am I doing wrong?

```
INSERT INTO my_table (geom_moyenne) 
SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_ Collect (geometry))AS geom_moyenne   
FROM my_table   
GROUP BY road ;
```

--

```
UPDATE my_table 
SET geom_moyenne = ST_Centroid(ST_ Collect (geometry)) AS geom_moyenne  
FROM my_table   
GROUP BY road;
```

I also have a second table my_roads that has road (same road numbers as my_table)and geom_moyenne columns, and I'm trying to put the same selection in the geom_moyenne column, but can't do that either (I need it in my_roads table actually but just thought it would be easier to first fill it in the same table and then eventually copy to another).

Answer (score 1):

Finally I managed to solve it in a completely different way. Sorry DPSSpacial but your script was too complex for me to understand what is going on there. I had to simplify.

First I added a geometry column to my road_table:

```
ALTER TABLE road_table ADD geom_moyenne geometry ;
```

Then I created a temporary table out of my selection:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_geom_table AS
SELECT ST_Centroid(ST_Union(geometry))AS geom_moyenne , road
    FROM my_table --my initial table that contains the points
    GROUP BY road;
```

Then I could easily copy the geom column between both tables:

```
UPDATE road_table
SET geom_moyenne = m.geom_moyenne
FROM temp_geom_table m
WHERE road = m.road;
```

Voilà!

Answer (score 0):

Well you've picked a tough problem to start out with! But doable.

I'll post the SQL to do this twice - once without comments, and once with.

Basically you have to not only create the new geometry from the roads, you have to determine the closest centroid point to the source point. That is done using a KNN nearest neighbor operator in PostGIS, which is an extremely useful tool especially for a problem like this.

You can also benefit from using subqueries to put stuff together.

Anyway, here's the SQL:

```
;with

cte_sch as (
select
    s.schnum
    , s.geom
from
    public.test_points_closestroad as s 
    )

    , cte_coll as (
select
    ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) as geom_coll
from ccd."CCD_StreetCenterlines" as st
    group by    st.fullname 
    )
    
    
update
    public.test_points_closestroad as r set
    geom_coll = new_geom.geom_coll
from
    (
    select
        sch.schnum
        , road.geom_coll
    from
        cte_sch as sch
        , lateral ( 
                select geom_coll from cte_coll as c
                order by sch.geom <-> c.geom_coll limit 1
                ) as road 
    ) as new_geom
where
    r.schnum = new_geom.schnum;
```

And here it is with comments to understand what is going on:

```
;with cte_sch as (
--just get everything from 
select s.schnum --ID of the points we'll need later
, s.geom --existing point geometry
from public.test_points_closestroad as s 
)

, cte_coll as (
--do the collecting and centroids of each road
--grouping on the fullname column
select
    ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geom)) as geom_coll
from
    ccd."CCD_StreetCenterlines" as st

group by
    st.fullname

)

update  public.test_points_closestroad  as r 
--only using the r alias for the where clause on the update (see bottom)

--geom_coll is the name of the empty column
--as well as the name of the collected road centroid 
set geom_coll = new_geom.geom_coll from (
--create a sub query putting the above two CTE's together
-- ensuring the schnum / ID is available 
-- which is needed to join the new geometry to the existing record
select 
 sch.schnum
, road.geom_coll
 from cte_sch as sch 
 --this is the magic of the KNN nearest neighbor operator
, lateral (select geom_coll from cte_coll as c
order by sch.geom <-> c.geom_coll limit 1)  as road

) as new_geom --alias of the subquery

--ensure the records from the sub query join to the original points
--using the schnum / ID
where r.schnum = new_geom.schnum;
```

Let me know what you think...

Comment: I'm tryig to decipher what you wrote, I've got an impression that you're using more columns that I have in my table. 
is schnum my id_point ? 
why ccd."CCD_StreetCenterlines" and what it is? 
what is fullname column? 
Is your query supposed to fill the geom_coll in the same table (table of points) or the second table (table of roads)? 

I'm sorry but it is really hard for me to understand what is going on if you are not using the names of my columns in the query...

Comment: I only got so far and I'm completely lost with the rest (the last line is probably wrong):

;with

cte_sch as (
select
    s.id_point
    , s.geometry
from
    public.my_table as s 
    )

    , cte_coll as (
select
    ST_Centroid(ST_Collect(geometry)) as geom_coll
from public.my_table as s
    group by    s.road
    )
    
    
update
    public.my_table as s set
    s.geom_moyenne = cte_coll.geom_coll